# Error from openpgpjs example: 'openpgp.encrypt is not a function'

Tags: javascript, encryption, npm, openpgp, openpgp.js

I'm getting 'openpgp.encrypt is not a function' error while trying the example given at the openpgp.js github page:  https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs/blob/master/README.md#getting-started

Following the example presented and after installing with `npm install --save openpgp`

I then tried the snippets labeled 'setup' and 'Encrypt and decrypt Uint8Array data with a password'

```
// Set up

var openpgp = require('openpgp'); // use as CommonJS, AMD, ES6 module or via window.openpgp

openpgp.initWorker({ path:'openpgp.worker.js' }) // set the relative web worker path

openpgp.config.aead_protect = true // activate fast AES-GCM mode (not yet OpenPGP standard)

//  Encrypt and decrypt Uint8Array data with a password

var options, encrypted;

options = {
    data: new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x01, 0x01]), // input as Uint8Array (or String)
    passwords: ['secret stuff'],              // multiple passwords possible
    armor: false                              // don't ASCII armor (for Uint8Array output)
};

openpgp.encrypt(options).then(function(ciphertext) {
    encrypted = ciphertext.message.packets.write(); // get raw encrypted packets as Uint8Array
});

options = {
    message: openpgp.message.read(encrypted), // parse encrypted bytes
    password: 'secret stuff',                 // decrypt with password
    format: 'binary'                          // output as Uint8Array
};

openpgp.decrypt(options).then(function(plaintext) {
    return plaintext.data // Uint8Array([0x01, 0x01, 0x01])
});
```

Here is the error:

```
TypeError: openpgp.encrypt is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/tgrego/1/Src/Example/Javascript/Node.js/OpenPgp/openpgpExamp.js:20:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3
```

Comment: Checking openpgp in the debugger shows .encryptMessage is a method of openpgp, but not .encrypt.  However trying the code with encryptMessage replacing encrypt still failed.

Comment: Perhaps this is better suited as an issue on GitHub. This seems to me like somebody has forgotten to update the documentation after fiddling with code.

Comment: Thanks  Artjom.  I just submitted the issue at the GitHub repository.

Answer (score 1):

Installing with `npm install --save openpgp@2.2.1` resolved the version issue.

Also, to make the example work, the decryption section needs to be embedded in the callback function of the encryption section as follows:

```
var openpgp = require('openpgp'); // use as CommonJS, AMD, ES6 module or via window.openpgp

openpgp.initWorker({ path:'openpgp.worker.js' }) // set the relative web worker path

openpgp.config.aead_protect = true // activate fast AES-GCM mode (not yet OpenPGP standard)


var options, encrypted;

options = {
    data: new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x01, 0x01]), // input as Uint8Array (or String)
    passwords: ['secret stuff'],              // multiple passwords possible
    armor: false                              // don't ASCII armor (for Uint8Array output)
};

openpgp.encrypt(options).then(function(ciphertext) {
    encrypted = ciphertext.message.packets.write(); // get raw encrypted packets as Uint8Array

    options = {
        message: openpgp.message.read(encrypted), // parse encrypted bytes
        password: 'secret stuff',                 // decrypt with password
        format: 'binary'                          // output as Uint8Array
    };

    openpgp.decrypt(options).then(function(plaintext) {
        console.log (plaintext.data);
        return plaintext.data // Uint8Array([0x01, 0x01, 0x01])
    });

});
```